# При открытии попапа профиля невозможно изменить данные

Tags: javascript

при открытии попапа профиля в консоли ошибка. Скрин http://joxi.ru/1A5YdBpS46gDVA
не могу изменить профиль. При сабмите ошибка http://joxi.ru/Dr8YZBESKLQzpm и ничего не изменяется

Еще заметил ошибки:
При открытии попапа профиля нужно вставлять в его инпуты данные пользователя, которые отображены сейчас на сайте, чтобы можно было их отредактировать сразу и обновить.

```
export default class UserInfo {
  constructor({ nameAuthor, infoAuthor }) {
    this._nameAuthor = nameAuthor;
    this._infoAuthor = infoAuthor;
  }

  getUserInfo() {
    this._userInfoValues = {
      nameAuthor: this._nameAuthor.textContent,
      infoAuthor: this._infoAuthor.textContent,
    };
    return this._userInfoValues;
  }

  setUserInfo(newData) {
    this._nameAuthor.textContent = newData.nameAuthor;
    this._infoAuthor.textContent = newData.infoAuthor;
    }
}
```

````
 export const authorProfileInput = document.querySelector('.form__input_info_name-author');

export const authorJobProfileInput = document.querySelector('.form__input_info_name-author-job');```
````

Comment: Покажите как вы создайте объект класса.

Comment: Кхм.. Если это инпуты, то может быть не `textContent`, а `value`?? :) Хотя.. Все равно вы пытаетесь обратиться к `null`. Вы что-то не так передаете.